# Python dictionary - list issue (2.7.XX)

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary

I'm fairly new to python and I'm currently trying to do an exercise which I can't seem to work out.

Basically I have a long text (.txt) document which contains an email conversation. Now from the I have to read through the document and list all the email addresses ( which I can get right )

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "file.txt"
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    email = line.strip()
if email.startswith('From: '):
    name = email.split()
    print name
```

The output from this is a multi line list with 2 parts in the line.

```
['From:', 'email@address.com'] 
['From:', 'email@address.com']
['From:', 'email@address.com']
['From:', 'email@address.com']
['From:', 'email@address.com']
```

Now, my problem is that I have to put just those email addresses into a dictionary and have a count next to it, such as

```
email@address.com 5
```

So now I have added the loop to the code with the .get() function

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "file.txt"
handle = open(name)
for line in handle:
    email = line.strip()
if email.startswith('From: '):
    name = email.split()
    print name
for names in name:
    count[names] = count.get(names,0) + 1
    print count
```

At this point I get the full list and the output below:

```
{'From:': 1}
{'From:': 1, 'email@address.com': 1}
```

How would I now only get the email@address.com in the dictionary? It seems that I cant get the full list into the dictionary and I get the "From" added which I don't need. I will then try write the rest to print the biggest count in the dictionary which will then be my desired output.

I have been stuck on this for a while and I need to unfortunately keep it simple and plus minus the functions I've used. I have tried to look around the internet and here but nothing I have tried, so far, helps me out. I am fairly new at this so I am sorry if the fix is obvious

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = (['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com']
)

emails = {}
for i in lst:
    email = i[1]
    if email in emails.keys():
        emails[email] += 1
    else:
        emails[email] = 1
print emails

>>> {'email@address.com': 5}
```

Add your found mails to the list then iterate over it, or you can do this in a single pass

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "file.txt"
handle = open(name)

emails = {}
for line in handle:
    email = line.strip()
    if email.startswith('From: '):
        name = email.split()
        if name[1] in emails.keys():
            emails[name[1]] += 1
        else:
            emails[name[1]] = 1

print emails
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help me, i need to retrieve the info from my "name" variable (info you put as lst)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more concise solution using list comprehensions.

```
lst = (['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@address.com'],
['From:', 'email@addres.com'],
['From:', 'email@addres.com'],
['From:', 'email@addres.com'],
['From:', 'email1@addres.com'],
['From:', 'email1@addres.com'],
['From:', 'email1@addres.com'],
['From:', 'email1@addres.com'],
['From:', 'email1@addres.com'],
)

unique_set = set([x[1] for x in lst])

emails = {}
for i in unique_set:
    emails[i] = len([x for x in lst if x[1] == i])

print emails
```

In the above code I am first creating a collection of unique entries in your list by checking the second item in your email tuple i.e *x[1]*. A python *set* does this for you. Once I have this collection, I filter the input list and count the number of entries in the original list using the *len* method on the resultant list. I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

[open()](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html) returns a file object, and is most commonly used with two arguments: open(filename, mode).

```
f = open('filename', 'r')#In your case you are reading from the file.

    for line in f:
            print line,
```

Before the loop you can set all your conditions to start reading from "From: "